# Ansible to get aws instances software list

Tags: ansible

I want to get list of services installed and their versions on debian ec2 instances.

I am unable to understand how can i get the list of packages which dpkg --list shows because i want to get this list through ansible on my little server farm.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to simply run a shell task:

```
- shell: dpkg --list
  register: packages
```

Now you have the result stored in `packages.stdout_lines`.

If you only want the package names, run something like this

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v "deinstall" | cut -f1
```

To run the task on the Ansible control host you need to delegate the task:

```
- shell: dpkg --list
  register: packages
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Now the command is executed on the control host (localhost) and the result stored in `packages.stdout_lines`

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. This has given me a good progress in learning Ansible. However I am unable to find packages.stdout_lines file anywhere. I added shell: dpkg --list >> somelog.txt in playbook but it created output file on the remote host instead of ansible server. Basically I want to get packages list of all instances on Ansible server

Comment: In my above task the result is registered as the variable `packages`. The stdout of the executed shell command is stored in the property `stdout_lines`. Therefore you can access the stdout as `packages.stdout_lines`. This is not a file but a varaible.

Comment: Try a task like this: `- debug: msg="{{ packages.stdout_lines }}"`

Comment: I added an example above for running the task on the Ansible control host.

Comment: When I run playbook with the content below it works:  `---
- hosts: host
  tasks:
   - shell: dpkg --list
     register: packages`     but after adding the line `delgate_to: localhost`  it does not work and says 'ERROR: delgate_to is not a legal parameter at this level in an Ansible Playbook'
     register: packages

Comment: Sorry, typo. *delegate_to*

Comment: Great. The playbook is now working. How can I read the content from variable: packages.stdout_lines. I dont see this variable while running printenv command.                         My playbook is now: '---
- hosts: host
  tasks:
   - name: Get Packages List
     shell: dpkg --list
     register: packages
     delegate_to: localhost'

Comment: The registered variables live in your current ansible run. There is nothing written to an environment variable on your control host. I suggest you start reading some Ansible docs to get a basic understanding how it actually works. http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#registered-variables

Comment: Basically my all purpose is to gather a list of installed packages and services along with their versions and store them on Ansible host server and later save them in document to manage documentation of my instances. In the current scenario either its printing on stdout or its placing it in ansible variable. Is there anyway I can throw the output to a file placed in Ansible host so that I can process that file later.

Answer (score 0):

```
---
- hosts: hostblockname
  tasks:
   - name: Get Packages List
     shell: dpkg --list > packageslist
     register: packages
   - fetch: src=/root/packageslist dest=/root/packagesdirectory/
```

I added the above playbook which helped serving my purpose. There may be room for optimization but somehow I am able to get it done for me.

I wanted to get list of all packages installed in a proper format on all Cloud Instances. Then I wanted to get list of all packages in a file on my Ansible server.
This playbook first generated list of installed packages on remote instances and then fetched those files back to main Ansible host.

The command to run playbook was:
ansible-playbook -i hostslistfile myplaybook.yml

myplaybook.yml is as above.

hostslistfile  is simple file which is as below:
[hostblockname]
192.168.0.144:22